# RxJava2 merged Observable doesn't stop

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Why `merge` operator doesn't stopped after `obs2` onCompleted? I am looking at diagram from this book

```
"Reactive Programming on Android with RxJava"
```

[image]

From my point of view if any of merged Observables is `onCompleted`, then another Observable also terminates (completed).

But its not. why so?

Here is my code. Obs1 should terminate just after Obs2, but it is endless

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        Observable.merge(obs1, obs2)
                .subscribe(data -> Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(data)));
    }

    Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(data -> "obs1: " + data);

    Observable obs2 =
            Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .filter(data -> data < 5)
                    .map(data -> "obs2: " + data)
                    .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "done"));

D/MainActivity: obs1: 0
                obs2: 1
                obs2: 2
                obs2: 3
D/MainActivity: obs2: 4
                done
D/MainActivity: obs1: 1
D/MainActivity: obs1: 2
D/MainActivity: obs1: 3
D/MainActivity: obs1: 4
D/MainActivity: obs1: 5
D/MainActivity: obs1: 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behaviour because first observable still emitting items on every second. Merge operator's onComplete method does not trigger until observed items onComplete method called

Comment: `takeWhile` doesnt solve this problem. Obs1 still working https://pastebin.com/59anJg9t

Comment: @Masquitos Sorry, I confused observables. But the reason of  merge operation not completed is your first observable still emitting items

Comment: Yeah, you have an interactive marble diagram here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html. Play around with it (including termination signs) so that you can understand operator behavior in every case.

Comment: @Masquitos No it is correct, but in your case is different, your first observable not completed, it still emitting item on every second

Comment: @Masquitos If you add onNext statement on first observable you see it is still emitting,
Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(data -> "obs1: " + data).doOnNext(data->  Log.d(TAG, "obs1"+data ));

Comment: @gokhan so why on image main observalbe terminate after firs observable terminated?

Comment: @Masquitos you are right image is wrong, the correct one is  http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html